# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError | Caused by: com.b.a.c.b: 'com.b.a.b.a' requires the 'sequence' attribute

Tags: java, android, exception, gson

I am getting following exception in different areas of my project. And worst thing is I have no idea what it is... I do not have com.b.a.c.b package in my project. I tried searching on web but still, I am not understanding what is causing this exception.

This exception is thrown on `onCreate()` method (I guess) after an `Intent` call from another `Activity`.

**Note:** I am using gson 2.2.4 with POJO method, just before this I got this exception, I was facing error in JSON creation with same kind of value `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, etc... instead of POJO variable names. I resolved it using `@SerializedName("")` annotation over all variable names in POJO class.

following is error log:

```
12-17 18:12:36.346: I/Timeline(2526): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.shezartech.iitjeeacademy.ui.activity time:15338553
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sequence []
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:665)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.b.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.b.a.l.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.shezartech.iitjeeacademy.ui.activity.RegisterActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
12-17 18:12:36.406: W/System.err(2526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
12-17 18:12:36.406: D/AndroidRuntime(2526): Shutting down VM
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526): Process: com.shezartech.iitjeeacademy.ui.activity, PID: 2526
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.shezartech.iitjeeacademy.ui.activity.RegisterActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526): Caused by: com.b.a.c.b: 'com.b.a.b.a' requires the 'sequence' attribute.
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     at com.b.a.l.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
12-17 18:12:36.406: E/AndroidRuntime(2526):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: is the code proguarded by any chance?

Comment: Looks like proguard obfuscation

Comment: is there any other way without disabling proguard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable proguard and than you will see that error will explain itself, you can do it from gradle file.

Comment: `buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }` you mean here ?

Comment: yes disable minifying for now after you find the error you can enable it again (make minifyEnabled false)

Comment: Done, Thank you Emrah.