# 'com.b.a.b.a' requires the 'sequence' attribute - Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Upon using `Proguard` for release, my app throws this exception when my `LoginFragment` is called. I saw this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335350/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-caused-by-com-b-a-c-b-com-b-a-b-a-re) where the user was recommended to turn off Proguard and the error would appear. When I turn off Proguard everything works as expected. Google brings up no results, perhaps there's an error with my Proguard config file? Warning: it's big.

The `Fragment` itself is a `support.v4.Fragment` so I would have thought the below line would keep "`sequence`".

```
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
01-06 10:57:12.615 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.myapp, PID: 26980
                                                   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                       at com.myapp.login.LoginFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                    Caused by: com.b.a.c.b: 'com.b.a.b.a' requires the 'sequence' attribute.
                                                       at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.b.a.f.t(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.b.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.b.a.l.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.myapp.login.LoginFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**Proguard config:**

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-verbose
-dontpreverify
-allowaccessmodification
-mergeinterfacesaggressively
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keepattributes *Annotation*

####################################################################  KEEP ANDROID SUPPORT V7 AND DESIGN

-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.** { *; }

####################################################################  REMOVE WARNINGS


-dontwarn android.support.design.internal.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**


####################################################################  REMOVE LOGGING

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** wtf(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}

####################################################################  ORG.APACHE.HTTP

-keep class org.apache.http.**
-keep interface org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**

####################################################################  WEVVIEW

-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient

####################################################################  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES LIB - ADS

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
#-keep class com.google.android.gms.**

# For Google Play Services
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}

####################################################################  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES LIB

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}

# Keep SafeParcelable value, needed for reflection. This is required to support backwards
# compatibility of some classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

# Needed when building against pre-Marshmallow SDK.
-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

# Keep metadata about included modules.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.** {
  public <fields>;
}

# Keep the implementation of the flags api for google-play-services-flags
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl {
  public <fields>; public <methods>;
}

# Retain generated class which implement Unbinder.
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(...); }

# Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name
# is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinding.
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }

-keep public class fr.castorflex.android.verticalviewpager.** {
    *;
}

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked inside my `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` and I was initialising an [`android-saripaar`](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) `Validator` but had not added a Proguard config for that library yet.

It worked when I added the below line:

```
-keep class com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.** {*;}
```